# Mouse wheel not working in firefox but only on one display

Tags: firefox, drivers, display, scroll-wheel

I have multiple displays on a windows XP box by using two video cards.

My scrollwheel does not work in firefox, but only for a specific display!

- This problem is specific to firefox, as outlook and rxvt scroll as expected in all displays.
- This problem is specific to a secondary display.
- This problem occurs with both microsoft wireless mouse and logitech usb mouse.

I run into this issue periodically, but dont know why it keeps coming back.

Perhaps the following table will help:

```
_Card_  _Display_  _Scroll_Ability_
Quadro  1 (dvi)    works
Radeon  2 (dvi)    works
Quadro  3 (vga)    does NOT work
Radeon  4 (vga)    works
```

I recently rotated Quatro 1 from landscape to portrait.
I recently updated Radeon drivers to allow portrait mode on Radeon 2 and 4

Any ideas?

--edit/update---edit/update---edit/update--
I've rebooted (of course), dropped and reinstalled my mouse,
and rearranged my monitors

Now I get the following:

```
_Card_  _Display_  _Scroll_Ability_
Quadro  1 (dvi)    works
Radeon  2 (dvi)    does NOT work
Quadro  3 (vga)    does NOT work
Radeon  4 (vga)    works
```

again all applications *except* firefox see the mousewheel just fine.
firefox only sees the mouse on display's 1 and 4 now

--edit/update---edit/update---edit/update--

Firefox scrolling with mousewheel still not working on secondary displays on dual video cards BUT....

it works fine on those displays when viewing emails on juno.com ! ?
more details... using ardvark to browse the DOM, it seems that I can use the scrollwheel when inside an iframe of the email, but not outside that iframe.

bizzare

--edit/update---edit/update---edit/update--

firefox in safe mode does not fix the ignoring of mouse wheel on select displays.
installing intellimouse mouse drivesr does not help (now all drivers are up-to-date).
tweakui (focus follows mouse) and clicking the mice wheels does not help.
IETab extension works (but is an unacceptable solution specifically because foxyproxy is bypassed).

trying a completely uninstall of firefox and reinstalling (already had latest version anyway).

fresh install of firefox 3.5.2 without any modification/personalization still wont scroll with the mousewheel on 2 of 4 displays.

arora, rxvt, outlook, notepad, etc... all are scrolling via mousewheel on all 4 displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root cause found!  Display ordering and the 'Primary Display' in windows!

In the 'Display Properties' dialog on windows,
all 'displays' to the 'left' of the 'primary display' are unable to use the scrollwheel in firefox.

Change the order of displays so that '1' is the left-most display and it works!
Selecting the left-most display, and checking the 'Use this device as the primary monitor' is a pretty good workaround.

I opened a bug with the firefox folks
(but with appropriately minor severity as there is a workaround):
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=512794

Comment: It looks like they fixed this in the current nightly builds.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing up your card/display combinations?  That could narrow it down easily.

Comment: made it worse :-( now both vga displays are not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

One could try looking here for a discussion about similar symtoms...
alas did not fix my specific issue, however.

http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?forumId=1&comments_parentId=9011

Answer (score 0):

Does [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/29459/how-to-make-mouse-wheel-to-scroll-control-under-mouse-cursor) shed any light onto your predicament?

Comment: link seems to discuss keyboard focus as it relates to scrollwheel behavior.  TweakUI focus follows mouse is what I am using.  I have not (yet) tried katmouse and/or WizMouse

Comment: @ericslaw - Might not help then - but I'd just seen the question so it struck a chord.