# How to make mouse wheel to scroll control under mouse cursor?

Tags: windows, mouse, scrolling

Currently, mouse wheel scrolls the control that has keyboard focus. That's not good when window has several scrollable controls, because I have to click control first and then scroll. And the same again when trying to scoll another control. Especially bad, when that control has some action associated with click (like MSDN's article list - it opens new article on click).
So, is there any tool to fix mouse scroll behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [WizMouse](http://jkontherun.com/2009/02/12/scroll-in-windows-without-the-cursor-focus/). Just some software I came across. Haven't tried it though but the comments on it seem good.

Comment: Add a description when you give a link, especially if the text says only "try this".

Comment: This is 'WizMouse'. Very similar to KatMouse (which has a few more options related to scrolling speed). Both work in Windows 7

Comment: This WizMouse Works ok for me.

Comment: Works on Windows 8

Answer (score 17):

Check out [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/). I think this will do what you want.

Comment: i use catmouse daily. It works great. Also has a feature to switch windows clicking the mouse wheel, which is pretty snazzy

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 now adds such an option to the Modern UI control panel under Input.

It does not make the scroll wheel work over combo boxes though, like KatMouse or AlwaysMouseWheel would do.